# What is a good design pattern for using an abstract superclass?

Tags: oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract, superclass

When you make a subclass of a class, when do you want to make the superclass `abstract` because by my knowledge, a superclass can do anything that a abstract class can. Am I right?

By making it abstract, you're just limiting yourself of instantiating the abstract class.

For example, there's two classes, A and B

```
class A {


}

class B extends A {


}
```

and

```
abstract class A {


}

class B extends A {


}
```

Are there any specific difference?

Or, is organizing the code conceptually the whole point of using abstract class as a super class? for example, you want to use abstract class in such a case that each of the subclasses is a more specific type of its abstract superclass (i.e. Fruit > apple, orange, banana, grape, strawberries, etc.) and you want to use non-abstract superclass in a relationship such as Dad and Son?

Can I get a general answer when to use abstract class and when not to? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not going to use the base class, the `abstract` class directly, make it abstract.

Such as

```
public abstract class Shape  {
   ...
```

You don't care about using a `Shape` directly, because it can mean anything, so it should be abstract to prevent instantiation. But abstract classes hold important information and functionality about *every* shape that sub-classes it. Such as the name of the shape, or area or side-count, or whatever.

Sometimes abstract classes don't implement functions because they have no knowledge of how sub-classes might want to do actually handle its processing. Or they know *what* to do, but simply *can't*. An example

```
public abstract class NumberInRange<N extends Number> 
    public abstract boolean isGreaterThanOrEqualToMinBound(N n_n);
```

A `Number` can't be directly compared against another, because it's not [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). But an int can:

```
public class IntInRange extends NumberInRange<Integer>  {
   public boolean isGreaterThanOrEqualToMinBound(Integer to_compareTo)  {
      return  (this.compareTo(to_compareTo) >= 0);
   }
```

So `NumberInRange` must be abstract, and `IntInRange` is concrete.

---

Your question also relates to the issue of [abstract-versus-interface](https://www.google.com/search?q=abstract%20versus%20interface%20java). You can inherit multiple interfaces, but you only extend a single class (abstract or not). Interfaces therefore give you more flexibility.

...***which*** brings up the issue of [inheritance-versus-composition](https://www.google.com/search?q=composition%20not%20inheritance%20java)... but we'll leave that one for later  :)

Answer (score 2):

The main reason is [delegation](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-inheritance-with-delegation).  Interfaces are great for contracts (ie., if you are saying that you implement my interface, these are the things you *must* do).  However, interfaces don't enforce any functionality, just that you are adhering to these method names with such-and-such parameters and return some pre-negotiated type.

Abstraction is a way to provide base functionality and force you to provide implementation details about what *you* need to accomplish.  Abstract classes are very useful when the class can best be put to use as an [anonymous class](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~tmh/courses/allJava/Anonymous.html) where all but the minutiae details of what happens in the filled-in methods are needed.  This pattern is used as adapters for [Event handlers in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html) quite extensively.

Answer (score 1):

The super class is more of a general class. Now suppose, you want to develop an application that has language translation involved. What you will do is, declare a abstract class, Speak, that has the general method, say translate(). You have developers from Russia, China, India and so on. The translation of a particular language will differ from others (Russian will be different from Mandarin). So you leave the implementation details to the programmer. He will implement the details as per the specifications. There will be classes such as Russian which will extend the abstract class Speak and implement the translate() method wrt the language. All the implementations of the translate method will be independent and will be decided by the developer. Hope this helps